# Lock screen with Nova launcher not showing new icons

Tags: settings, lock-screens, htc-one, nova-launcher

I have an HTC One (M8) and downloaded Nova Launcher to customize my layout. I downloaded the Black Glass ADW Theme and it looks great. However, on my lock screen it is still showing the app icons from my HTC Blinkfeed. (Aside from the theme, I have the exact same apps on the launch bar in both the Blinkfeed and Nova home screens.)

I have my alarm on my launch bar so it shows on the lockscreen. When my phone went off this morning, it was the Blinkfeed alarm settings rather than the alarm settings through Nova.

I've been trying to figure out how to get the icons to match both in the look and the functionality but don't know how.. help please! :)

Comment: Nova doesn't replace lockscreen, you'd need a third party lockscreen app.... until Lollipop comes out then you're stuck with the lollipop lockscreen for now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, how are you enjoying Nova **launcher?** There is your problem: Nova launcher replaces the home screen **only**. It does not alter the lockscreen. For that, you need a custom lockscreen.  These often come with a lot of..... crap you don't want or need.

Answer (score 0):

Its based off Sense's dock icons. Go to the sense launcher and set the dock icons and then set the launcher back to nova.